# Permission denied for udp client

Tags: python, udp, permission-denied

I have needed to whip up a UDP client to for test but when ı run,it gives me this error.I don't understand why?

client.bind((target_host, target_port))
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

```
import socket

target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_port = 80


client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)


client.sendto("AAABBBCCC".encode(encoding = 'utf-8'),(target_host,target_port))
client.bind((target_host, target_port))


data, addr = client.recvfrom(1024)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use .bind() method for client, try delete this function call.

```
import socket
target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_port = 80

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client.connect((target_host, target_port))
client.send("AAABBBCCC".encode(encoding = 'utf-8'))
data = client.recv(1024)
print(data)
```

Comment: when ı use "call" function, i give this error 'socket' object has no attribute 'call'

Comment: updated answer. Just delete "client.bind((target_host, target_port))"